# 'Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am developing an android application with home page same as facebook app. I have inflated a layout to my home page by using the following code.

```
View app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app, null);
```

I have a tabhost in the layout 'app'. The home page is extending activity. When I run the application the app is throwing error

> 'Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.tabhost''

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

remove extends TabHost from your class.

Comment: I am not extending TabHost in my class. I have a home page that extends Activity and I am inflating the layout app in my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

try following code.

```
TabHost t = getTabHost();
TabSpec tab = t.newTabSpec(label)
               .setIndicator(label, icon)
               .setContent(intent);
t.addTab(tab);
```

or  change your tabhost id to

```
<TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```